# Isomorphicity of fields.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Given two irreducible polynomials $f$ and $g$.

> What are some conditions under which we can conclude that the corresponding number fields are non-isomorphic?

For instance if $\deg(f) \neq \deg (g)$, then the corresponding number fields are non-isomorphic. For instance, if $\operatorname{disc}(f)$ and $\operatorname{disc}(g)$ are not in the same square class $\dfrac{\Bbb Q ^*}{\Bbb Q ^{*2}}$, then the corresponding number fields are non-isomorphic.

> How can we realize that the number field corresponding to $x^5-pq=0$, is not isomorphic to the number field corresponding to $x^5-pq^2=0$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many methods to distinguish two different fields using both more or less sophisticated methods by looking at invariants of the field  (degree, discriminant, local ramification, signature, etc.) For the particular case of $x^5 - pq$ and $x^5 - pq^2$, note that if the fields were the same there would be $\alpha, \beta \in K$ such that $\alpha^5 = pq$ and $\beta^5 = pq^2$, and so $\gamma = \beta/\alpha$ would satisfy $\gamma^5 = q$, and  $\delta = \alpha^2/\beta$ would satisfy $\delta^5 = p$. By degree considerations, this implies that the field $K$ is equal to $\mathbf{Q}(\gamma)$ and $\mathbf{Q}(\delta)$. The easiest way to distinguish these is by using local ramification at $p$ and $q$, but you can also use linear algebra...

Comment: Thanks for your perfect answer. Your answer helped me too much. Let $\alpha$ be an algebraic number. Also, assume that $K$ is a number field that is isomorphic to $\Bbb Q (\alpha)$. (I am not sure, but) I guess we can find a conjugate of $\alpha$, like $\beta$ such that $K=\Bbb Q (\beta)$. In other words, I guess that the only isomorphic fields are the fields corresponding to the conjugates of the minimal polynomial. (It is just my guess, and maybe it is not true)

Comment: Why should those two fields should be the same? I can see that $\Bbb Q (\sqrt[5]{pq}) \subseteq \Bbb R$ and $\Bbb Q (\sqrt[5]{pq^2}) \subseteq \Bbb R$. I can not see how the isomorphicity of fields implies they should be the same. (Even in this special case)